# Once and for all, does app with background location boot itself after reboot?

Tags: ios, background, location, boot, reboot

I've read a lot of questions here, some says there is a need to set VOIP mode and the app should boot itself after reboot.
But my app mostly do background location based stuff.
My app is not VOIP based but it is necessery to restart it after reboot.
Is there any way to do it or it can never be done?

By the eay, I set the VOIP key in the plist file and my app still not boot itself after reboot.

Any ideas mates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to test to make sure you are implimenting everything correctly. Everyone reports this to work properly with the voip key added.

[VoIP iOS example](https://github.com/lithium3141/BootLaunch)

Comment: ok, thanks.
will apple ban my app if i lie and add the VOIP key and don't user VOIP in my app?

Comment: More than likely they will just not approve it. They do test any functionality that is reported to be in the app and require all features to be there at the time of testing. I'm 100% sure they will test the voip key feature.